# Babel doesn't work in Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I’m hosting a nodejs project on server, that uses ES6 syntax, and I used babel-cli to compile it. I don't have any problem in my localhost, but when i host it I get this error:

> import express from 'express';^^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

my node version is v10.16.0

`package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "example",
"version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "nodemon ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
 "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
 "express": "^4.16.3",
 "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
"mongodb": "^3.1.6",
"mongoose": "^5.3.1",
"nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
"nodemon": "^1.18.4",
"randomstring": "^1.1.5",
"shortid": "^2.2.14"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
 }
}
```

and for `.babelrc`:

```
      {
    "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-0"
]
```

}

```
import express from 'express';
   ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules              /cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Are you host and localhost using the same node version?

Comment: @zero298 hi, no ,my localhost`s node version is v8.11.1

Comment: @zero298  and host's node version is v10.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this link

https://www.codementor.io/iykyvic/writing-your-nodejs-apps-using-es6-6dh0edw2o

the problem was solved

Comment: How? Can you maybe explain what the issue was and what solved it. The link points to a very long setup tutorial.